# chaining imports-loader and exports-loader with a library that overwrites the module variable

Tags: javascript, webpack, emscripten, vorbis, webpack-loader

I'm trying to load an audio encoding library called libvorbis.js which is an emscripten compiled version of vorbis.

libvorbis.js requires to be executed with the window variable in it's scope and leaves the classes exposed as a var without an exports declaration.

Normally it would be easy to chain imports-loader and exports-loader to fetch such a file.
Using-

```
require 'imports-loader?this=>window!exports-loader?VorbisMediaRecorder!libvorbis.js/build/libvorbis.js'
```

which will expose the window object as 'this' inside libvorbis.js and take VorbisMediaRecorder out as the return to this which is needed by my other modules/code to be run later.

HOWEVER, libvorbis.js itself overwrites the 'module' variable which screws up exports-loader from exporting

libvorbis.js has this check in it's code

```
// node.js Environment
var module;
if (module && module.exports) {
    makeVorbisEncoderModule({}, module);
}

// Web Worker Environment
if (!module && this.document === undefined) {
    VorbisWorkerScript.main(this);
}
```

this overwrites module which causes webpack to throw this error

```
commons.js:142 TypeError: Cannot set property 'exports' of undefined
```

as it's trying to run

```
/*** EXPORTS FROM exports-loader ***/
module.exports = VorbisMediaRecorder;
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? I really don't want to fork libvorbis and modify it's source.

The libvorbis.js library was written to be included as a script on the page.

Answer (score 3):

So I solved my particular problem with using file-loader. It will load the script exactly like a file with a src etc... hence it can be run without issues.

```
# libvorbis must be resolved in window scope, use the file-loader
require 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!libvorbis.js/build/libvorbis.js'
```